# Expansion with conditional ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, iterable, expansion

Simple question: Is there a way to use an expansion inside a conditional statement using the ternary operator?

```js
const a = 1, b = 2;

// Works
console.log(...[ a, b ]);

// Works
console.log(...(a ? [ a, b ] : [ 'Not found' ]));

// Doesn't work
console.log(a ? ...[ a, b ] : 'Not found');
```

Comment: Doubt that. Ternary operator takes expressions after the condition. Expressions evaluate to a single value.

Comment: In that case, the last example should work. It looks like the ternary operator can only return the same type for both conditions

Comment: No, it should not. Ternary operator needs to result in an assignment expression. And spread operator does not result in one. The same way you can't do `const a = ...[a, b]` or `const a = ...["a"]` for that matter. The type of the expressions does not matter. Using the spread syntax in the ternary operator like this will result in a syntax error. No condition evaluation takes place.

Comment: Ah, yes. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn’t currently possible. The [`…` spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), like its name tells us, is a part of the syntax of the language and not a ‘normal’ operator that deals with expressions (à la `+` or `typeof`). The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) needs *expressions* after the `?` and `:`, so you can’t use the syntax in those spots.

You’ll have to do e.g.

```js
condition
    ? console.log(…)
    : console.log(…)
```

Comment: That explains it. Instead of repeating console.log(), I can always spread the resulting ternary expression and use an array of length 1 in the false condition so it can be expanded, like this:
console.log(...(condition ? [ trueExpr1, trueExpr2 ] : [ falseExpr ]));

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No

No, because in some cases it is not supported

Yes, you need to use it in the way it supports, basically manipulate it

For example

```js
const a = 1, b = 2;

// Works
console.log(...[ a, b ]);

// Doesn't work
//console.log(a ? ...[ a, b ] : 'Not found');
//use this 
a ? console.log(...[a,b]) : "Not Found"

//you can have other ways too to achieve this
```

Comment: The last false condition won't print. It'll return a string without a function. Please see my second working example

Comment: you cannot use spread operator in ternary, thats what issue is . LIke condition ? ...some : "yes" would not work, thats what happening in your case. console.log can accepts console.log(...some)